# Outlook Web Access and Rules

Tags: microsoft-outlook, exchange

One of my clients would prefer that I have an email address in their domain. They run SBS 2k8 so I just monitor my email from them (and *their* clients) via Outlook Web Access.

No POP or IMAP access, only OWA. No VPN access either, so no "real" Outlook. ***Just*** OWA.

I figured I'd build an outlook rule to forward mail from that account to an account that I monitor -- that way I won't need to keep IE open all the time to monitor email. However, I just can't seem to get the dang rule to work and am hoping someone here can give me a nudge or pointer.

From OWA, I click on Options -> Rules and edit my current rule that *kinda* works. The rule is supposed to forward the email sent to me and then move it to a folder. It does move it to a folder... just never seems to forward it.

The rule looks like this:

> Apply this rule after the message arrives
>   where my name is in the To box
>   redirect it to **myaddresss@mydomain.com**
>      and move it to the **Forwarded to MyEmail** folder
>   except with **"ALERT"** in the subject

As I mentioned, mail does get moved, just never redirected. I've tried "Forward" and "redirect" actions with the same results.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right then. So I just broke down and had him configure a forwarder for me on his Exchange server. Problem solved, no rules necessary.

original issue to remain a mystery.

Answer (score 0):

Remember you can always try RPC over HTTP (Outlook Anywhere) and then the user can use real outlook whereever and whenever. Just a pointer. Good luck :D